# Added JS file shown in view page, but gives 404 error when clicked

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, http-status-code-404

After the following code has been created in the child theme's function.php,

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'js_files');
function js_files() {
wp_register_script('ajax_call_mkto', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/something.js', array('jquery'), false);
wp_enqueue_script('ajax_call_mkto');
```

}

I checked the view page source and clicked on the link to see if it works, after clicking it, it gives me a 404 Not Found page. Is there something wrong with my JS file?

```
var $k = jQuery.noConflict();

$k('#something .somethinghere("yolo")').click(function() {
var $this = $k(this);

// Ajax call
ajaxConnection($this);
});

function ajaxConnection(item) {

alert('IT WORKS!');

}
```

This is the error I get in the console log:

> *404 (Not Found) somewebsite.com/:79 Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html*

---

**UPDATE**

**I figured it out.**

I had my scripts folder in the child theme directory. Instead of using "get_template_directory_uri()", which gets the directory from the parent's theme folder, I have to user "get_stylesheet_directory_uri()" to get the fold from the child theme.

Thanks for the assistance! It was my small mistake.

Comment: You're missing a slash `/js/file.js`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri#Examples

Comment: You're right. After adding the"/", it still gives me a 404 error. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Please, add your solution as an Answer and mark it solved.

Answer (score 0):

Waaaay too complicated. Try this:

`wp_enqueue_script('ajax_call_mkto', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/something.js');`

Remove the `wp_register_script();` as it's not needed.

Comment: In Word Press, aren't you suppose to register your script first and then enqueue it after?

Comment: **Okay, I figured it out.** 

I had my scripts folder in the child theme directory. Instead of using "get_template_directory_uri()", which gets the directory from the parent's theme folder, I have to user "get_stylesheet_directory_uri()" to get the fold from the child theme.

Thanks for the assistance! It was my small mistake.

Comment: @rolu, Not necessary. You can do it all in one go as in my example